# MacLaurin Series (Complex Numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis

so for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{z+4}$, I am supposed to find the Maclaurin Series and  give the region which it converges. Also, I am supposed to find $f^{(17)}(0)$ without computing the derivatives.

I know how to find the Maclaurin series, I am just struggling with finding the region it converges and how to compute the 17th derivative. Can someone please help me get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the maclaurin series of a function $f$ is written $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative. So it's asking for the coefficient at $n=17$. To find the radius of convergence, note that the geometric series is valid for $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the geometric series,
$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n.$$

Substitute $-z$ for $z$ to get the series for $1/(1+z)$. As for the other term, use the identity
$$\frac1{4+z}={1/4\over 1+z/4}.$$